# enable vertical scrolling of div inside div

Tags: css

I have the following div

```
<div><div class="test2"></div></div>
```

I'm trying to enable vertical scrolling of div with classname=test2.

How can I do so using html and css?

Answer (score 0):

overflow-y:scroll

check out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

for an quick example

Answer (score 0):

```
div.test2 {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

This will allow you to scroll if the content of test2 divs are greater than the set specifications.

You can also try `overflow-x:hidden`, `word-wrap:break-word` etc to get the scrolling and look of the div just how you want it.